# Is it possible to use the "Save & Edit" module with Rules?

Tags: 7, rules, notifications

I've created some rules to send notifications when changes some fields and  it works as I expected  when the user click on Save button.

After I enabled **[Save & Edit](https://www.drupal.org/project/save_edit)** module but I receive notifications both if I click on **Save** and **Save & Edit** .

I want receive a notifications only when click on **Save** .

Is possible? Or is there another approach to achieve the same result?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you have experience writing modules?  This seems like something you can do by executing php code in the rule.

Comment: Can you suggest me where I look for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a simple concept:
I could imagine using the [Rules Forms](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_forms) module with the following Form API conditions:

- Form ID: form_id == YOUR_CONTENT_TYPE_node_form
- Clicked button: $form_state['clicked_button']['#id'] !== 'edit-save-edit'

Answer (score 1):

> Or is there another approach to achieve the same result?

Another approach would be to add a field named "notify me" and of type Boolean

Then in rules Add Condition >> Data Comparison >> node:field-notify-me >> True

So you will receive e-mail only when the notify me is checked.

Comment: Thank you for reply but I don't want that the user choose if send me a notification. The notification must be generated only when Save.